# C# share same entity with nested using

Tags: c#, nested, using

I want to share an unique variable instatiated in a using statement when calling a function in that using scope.

I have a function B() which can be called from multiple ways. 
So I want the using being inside B always.

```
public void A()
{
  using(var db = new DB())
  {
    foreach(var item in items)
     { B();}
  }
}
 public void B()
    {
      using(var db = new DB())
      {
       // some code
      }
    }
```

I would like to do something like this but it doesn't work.
My goal is to avoid db being instated multiple time.

```
private DB _db;
public DB db {get { return _db ?? _db = new DB()}}

public void A()
{
  using(db)
  {
    foreach(var item in items)
     { B();}
  }
}
 public void B()
    {
      using(db)
      {
       // some code
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If B needs to use db, give db to B:

```
public void A()
{
  using(var db = new DB())
  {
    foreach(var item in items)
    { 
      //presumably this loop body will also do something with item
      B(db);
    }
  }
}

public void B(DB db)
{
   // some code using db
}

//in response to your comment. Maybe also make the B above as private
public void B()
{
    using(DB db){
      B(db);
    }
}
```

Your second form cannot work because a `using` block disposed of the variable when it finishes. You could however consider overriding dispose on your class so that your class wide db is disposed when your class is disposed, if you want to have a class wide db that lives for the life of your class. Ultimately this comes down to the lifecycle you want your class and the instances inside it, to have

Typically when the (more modern of the) systems I work on are implementing this data layer pattern, such as some Reader, they will take a db context via constructor parameter (dependency injection) and keep it for the life of the class, rather than each method making their own context in a using

Comment: I thought about that but its an example of DAL file. B can be called from BL too

Comment: Then that other place will also have to provide a db, or you can overload it so that the parameterless B will make a db and call the parameterised B. I made an edit to the code to give an example of this